# Using superhands component in a-frame, is it possible to rotate grabbed objects without using physics?

Tags: aframe, aframe-super-hands

I am using the updated [super-hands component](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component) in a-frame. I have replicated the basic example from the docs (see below).

```
<head>
  <title>Most Basic Super-Hands Example</title>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v4.1.2/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands@3.0.0/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets></a-assets>
    <a-entity>
      <a-camera></a-camera>
      <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box" super-hands hand-controls="left"></a-entity>
      <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box" super-hands hand-controls="right"></a-entity>
    </a-entity>
    <!-- hover & drag-drop won't have any obvious effect without some additional event handlers or components. See the examples page for more -->
    <a-box hoverable grabbable stretchable draggable dropppable color="blue" position="0 0 -1"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Which works well out of the box when it comes to grabbing objects and being able to affect their `position`, but not their `rotation`. I wondered if it was possible, (without using physics and adding a `static body` to the controller) to affect the `rotation` of the targeted objects?

I have been able to get the rotation working by adding the relevant mixin and phase-shift component [from this example](https://wmurphyrd.github.io/aframe-super-hands-component/examples/physics/) but given it seems possible to grab objects affecting their position I wondered if I could modify the basic example to change the `rotation` instead of the `position` (ideally I would be able to choose whether to affect `position`, `rotation` or both). I guess I'm imagining perhaps creating another component like `rotatable` or maybe a build on the grabbable component like `grabbable="property: rotation"` that I could add to the target objects.

I would like to know if this is possible in general as I would like to understand the component better so as to have more control. To give some context for this particular question however, I have a situation where the super-hands controllers are children of a `dynamic-body` and once a `static-body` is added, it causes problems with the behaviour of the parent `dynamic-body`.

Any advice appreciated as ever, if you need any more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the rotation without physics, you'll need to implement your own version of `grabbable` that does the matrix math. It would go something like this:

```
  tick: (function () {
    const grabeeMatrix = new window.THREE.Matrix4()
    const ignoreScale = new window.THREE.Vector3()
    return function () {
      if (this.grabber) {
        grabeeMatrix.multiplyMatrices(
          this.grabber.object3D.matrixWorld,
          this.grabOffsetMatrix
        )
        grabeeMatrix.multiplyMatrices(this.parentOffsetMatrix, grabeeMatrix)
        // using decomp over direct Object3D.matrix manipulation
        // keeps in sync with other A-Frame components
        grabeeMatrix.decompose(
          this.el.object3D.position,
          this.el.object3D.quaternion,
          // let stretchable manage scale
          ignoreScale
        )
      }
    }
  })(),
  resetGrabber: function () {
    if (!this.grabber) {
      return false
    }
    this.grabber.object3D.updateMatrixWorld()
    this.el.object3D.parent.updateMatrixWorld()
    // save difference between grabber world matrix and grabee world matrix
    this.grabOffsetMatrix
      .getInverse(this.grabber.object3D.matrixWorld)
      .multiply(this.el.object3D.matrixWorld)
    // save difference between grabee world and local matrices
    this.parentOffsetMatrix.getInverse(this.el.object3D.parent.matrixWorld)
    return true
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a complete example based on the code from W. Murphy (please comment if there's things to improve)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.misc.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands@^3.0.3/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
    <script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('rotatable', {
  dependencies: ['grabbable', 'stretchable', 'draggable'],
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('grab-start', (e) => this.start(e));
    this.el.addEventListener('grab-end', (e) => this.end(e));
    this.grabOffsetMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    this.parentOffsetMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  },
  tick: (function () {
    const grabeeMatrix = new window.THREE.Matrix4()
    const ignoreScale = new window.THREE.Vector3()
    return function () {
      if (this.grabbed) {
        grabeeMatrix.multiplyMatrices(
          this.grabber.object3D.matrixWorld,
          this.grabOffsetMatrix
        )
        grabeeMatrix.multiplyMatrices(this.parentOffsetMatrix, grabeeMatrix)
        // using decomp over direct Object3D.matrix manipulation
        // keeps in sync with other A-Frame components
        grabeeMatrix.decompose(
          this.el.object3D.position,
          this.el.object3D.quaternion,
          // let stretchable manage scale
          ignoreScale
        )
      }
    }
  })(),

  resetGrabber: function () {
    if (!this.grabber) {
      return false
    }
    this.grabber.object3D.updateMatrixWorld()
    this.el.object3D.parent.updateMatrixWorld()
    // save difference between grabber world matrix and grabee world matrix
    this.grabOffsetMatrix.copy(this.grabber.object3D.matrixWorld);
    this.grabOffsetMatrix.invert();
    this.grabOffsetMatrix.multiply(this.el.object3D.matrixWorld);
    // save difference between grabee world and local matrices
    this.parentOffsetMatrix.copy(this.el.object3D.parent.matrixWorld);
    this.parentOffsetMatrix.invert();
    return true;
  },
  start: function (e) {
    this.grabbed = true;
    this.grabber = e.detail.hand;
    this.resetGrabber();
  },
  end: function (e) {
    this.grabbed = false;
  }
});

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity>
        <a-camera></a-camera>
        <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box, a-sphere, a-cylinder" super-hands hand-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
        <a-entity sphere-collider="objects: a-box, a-sphere, a-cylinder" super-hands hand-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
      </a-entity>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-box grabbable rotatable stretchable draggable position="-1 0.5 -1.5" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere grabbable rotatable stretchable draggable position="0 1.25 -2" radius="0.5" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder grabbable rotatable stretchable draggable position="1 0.75 -1" radius="0.5" height="0.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-box grabbable rotatable stretchable draggable color="blue" depth="0.5" height="0.5" width="0.5" position="0 1.5 -1"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```